# Is it permissible for an engaged women and man to have sex and go out together and touch each other?

Tags: halal-haram, relationships

I had a doubt about engaged man and woman. Is it permissible for an engaged women and man to have sex and go out together and touch each other

Answer (score 3):

According to Shariah, engaged couples are regarded to be strangers for one another before marriage. As such all the normal rules of gender interaction would apply.

Therefore, it'd not be permissible for an engaged couple to go out together, touch each other and to have sex. It's strictly prohibited

For more [details](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/37123)

Comment: I thought there is no concept of engagement in Islam. Directly marriage. Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: engagement is just a cultural thing, it has nothing to do with Islam directly (keeping in Shariah limits)